# How do I show that $1$ is not an eigenvalue for $A$, by showing that there are no eigenvectors for $\lambda = 1$.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

Consider the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix}-1 &  3&  3& 3\\ 3&  1&  -1& 5\\ 3&  -1&  7& -1\\ 3&5&  -1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

How do I show that $1$ is not an eigenvalue for $A$, by showing that there are no eigenvectors for $\lambda = 1$?

This what I've done so far:

$$\left ( A - \lambda I \right )\vec{x} = \vec{0},$$

$$A-I =\begin{pmatrix}-2 &  3&  3& 3\\ 3&  0&  -1& 5\\ 3&  -1&  6& -1\\ 3&5&  -1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

I have do the Gaussian elimination to find the solution.

This is what my augmented matrix looks like in row-reduction form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1 &  3&  2& 8\\ 3&  0&  -1& 5\\ 0&  -7&  -5& -0\\ 0&1&  0&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$

What do I do from here?

Comment: You can not show that 1 is not an eigenvalue for A, by showing that there are no eigenvectors for λ=−1. This assumption is wrong. Imagine the matrix 2*I. It has neither -1 nor 1 as an eigenvalue. Did you intend 1 or -1 in both places?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Showing that $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ is the same as showing that the matrix $A - I$ is invertible.

You can do this by checking that its determinant is nonzero.

Alternatively, you can perform row reduction starting with $A - I$. Once you arrive at an upper triangular matrix with no zeros on the diagonal, you can be certain that $A - I$ is not invertible.

The matrix you wrote is not nearly in row-echelon form, because of the nonzero entries in the $(2,1)$-, $(3,2)$- and $(4,2)$-positions.

Answer (score 4):

A nice trick to show that $\lambda=1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ is to consider that over $\mathbb{F}_2$:
$$\det(A-I) =\det\begin{pmatrix}0 &  1&  1& 1\\ 1&  0&  1& 1\\ 1&  1&  0& 1\\ 1&1&  1&0\end{pmatrix}=1,$$
hence the determinant of $A-I$ is odd, so it is for sure different from zero.

As a curiosity, this is related with the fact the the number of derangements (permutations without fixed points) in $S_{2n}$ is always odd.

Comment: I just want to show that the row reduction does not equip us with any solution to the system of equations and nothing too fancy.

Comment: @user36829: By looking at the determinant of $(A−I)$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, you do not need to perform any reduction. The determinant is odd. Odd is non-zero. Stop. Anyway, if you prefer to perform a lenghty row-reduction, it is up to you. I just proposed a time-saving solution.